# File is not formatted correctly for Android Studio

Tags: function, flutter, android-studio

I am trying to add functions to my flutter app but when I add code to the index.js file the keywords are not color coded. I know this is something stupid but I am new to all of this.

I am using Android Studio 4.1.2

Here is what the file looks lke
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, you have a Flutter App which contains a index.js file? JavaScript is usually not part a Flutter project and Android Studio does not support JavaScript out of the box. Could you give some more info?

Comment: I am trying to add firebase functions to my app and I have been following this Youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrzvBulgBi0. If this is not the way to add functions to my flutter project can you please direct me to a good tutorial?